# Передать свойство в анонимную функцию TypeScript

Tags: typescript

как передать значение свойства класса в анонимную функцию. например:

```
class test
{
   n:number = 5;    
   update()
   {
      var f = function() {console.log(this.n)};
   }
}
```

в этом контексте this.n это совсем не моё значение. как именно правильно передать мой n?

Comment: Я не работал с typescript, но с учетом того, что он компилируется в привычный js - скорее всего, надо объявить переменную, куда и закешировать this: `var self = this;`. После этого вложенная функция будет видеть эту переменную из внешней области видимости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить вашу проблему можно двумя способами:

1-й:

```
class test
{
   n:number = 5;
   update()
   {
      var self = this;
      var f = function() {console.log(self.n)};
   }
}
```

2-й:

```
class test
{
   n:number = 5;
   update()
   {
      var f = () => {console.log(this.n)};
   }
}
```